# Kubernetes volumes: when is Statefulset necessary?

Tags: database, kubernetes, persistent-volumes, kubernetes-statefulset, persistent-volume-claims

I'm approaching k8s volumes and best practices and I've noticed that when reading documentation it seems that you always need to use **StatefulSet** resource if you want to implement persistency in your cluster:

> "StatefulSet is the workload API object used to manage stateful
> applications."

I've implemented some tutorials, **some of them use StatefulSet, some others don't**.

In fact, let's say I want to persist some data, I can have my stateless Pods (even MySql server pods!) in which I use a PersistentVolumeClaim which persists the state. If I stop and rerun the cluster, I can resume the state from the Volume with no need of StatefulSet.

I attach here an example of Github repo in which there is a stateful app with MySql and no StatefulSet at all:
https://github.com/shri-kanth/kuberenetes-demo-manifests

So **do I really need to use a StatefulSet** resource for databases in k8s? Or are there some specific cases it could be a necessary practice?

Answer (score 2):

PVCs are not the only reason to use Statefulsets over Deployments.
As the Kubernetes [manual](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#using-statefulsets) states:

StatefulSets are valuable for applications that require one or more of the following:

- Stable, unique network identifiers.
- Stable, persistent storage.
- Ordered, graceful deployment and scaling.
- Ordered, automated rolling updates.

You can read more about database considerations when deployed on Kubernetes here [To run or not to run a database on Kubernetes](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/databases/to-run-or-not-to-run-a-database-on-kubernetes-what-to-consider)

Answer (score 2):

[StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) is not the same as PV+PVC.

A StatefulSet manages Pods that are based on an identical container spec. Unlike a Deployment, a StatefulSet maintains a sticky identity for each of their Pods. These pods are created from the same spec, but are not interchangeable: each has a persistent identifier that it maintains across any rescheduling.

In other words it manages the deployment and scaling of a set of Pods , and provides guarantees about the ordering and uniqueness of these Pods.

> So do I really need to use a StatefulSet resource for databases in k8s?

It depends on what you would like to achieve.

StatefulSet gives you:

- Possibility to have a Stable Network ID (so your pods will be *always* named as `$(statefulset name)-$(ordinal)` )
- Possibility to have a Stable Storage, so when a Pod is (re)scheduled onto a node, its volumeMounts mount the PersistentVolumes associated with its PersistentVolume Claims.

> ...MySql and no StatefulSet...

As you can see, if your goal is just to run single RDBMS Pod (for example Mysql) that stores all its data (DB itself) on PV+PVC, then the StatefulSet is definitely an overkill.

However, if you need to run Redis cluster (distributed DB) :-D it'll be close to impossible  to do that without a StatefulSet (to the best of my knowledge and based on numerous threads about the same on StackOverflow).

I hope that this info helps you.

Comment: even for the redis cluster why a statefulset would be necessary? I have master election (if a node goes down) and load balancing among slaves nodes for reading. It seems a stable memory/network ID isn't necessary this way...

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo. I was thinking about the Apache Zookeeper.